# Equivalence relation for which there are infinitely many equivalence classes.

Tags: equivalence-relations

On set $\mathbb{R}$
  and the relation on it where $x\sim y$
  if $x^{4}=y^{4}$.
 Then $\sim $
 is equivalence relation for which there are infinitely many equivalence classes, one of which consists of a single element and, and the rest of two elements.
How to go about evaluating equivalence classes of $\sim$

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate" here?

Comment: finding the equivalence classes

Comment: If $x \sim y$, then $x^4 = y^4$. How can you solve for, say, $x$?

Comment: For instance, the real fourth roots of $\frac35$ will forn one equivalence class, and the real fourth roots of $0$ will form another equivalence class; however, the real fourth roots of $-1$ will not form an equivalence class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotient set is
 $$\mathbb{R}/\sim~~=\{\{a,-a\}|a \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

because $x \sim y$ if and only if $x=\pm y$